# C# Как дождаться завершения Reactive события, чтобы запустить следующее

Tags: c#, .net

возникла необходимость не просто пулять RX события в цикле друг за другом, а дожидаться выполнения текущего обработчика и только потом выстредивать следующим.

```
   protected async Task OneTimeActionAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        if (InDataQueue.TryDequeue(out var inData))
        {
           //ПОДПИСКА НА СОБЫТИЕ ОТПРАВКИ ПОРЦИИ ДАННЫХ
           var subscription = _dataProvider.RaiseSendDataRx.Subscribe(async provider =>
            {
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                try
                {
                    var dataExchangeSuccess = await _transport.DataExchangeAsync(_dataProvider.TimeRespone, _dataProvider, ct);
                    LastSendData = _dataProvider.InputData;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //LOG
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            });

            try
            {
                await _dataProvider.StartExchangePipline(inData);   // Запскаю конвеер подготовки данных, в нем и генирируются Rx события
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //LOG
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                subscription .Dispose();
            }
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000, ct);//DEBUG
    }
```

//_dataProvider

```
public async Task StartExchangePipline(InDataWrapper<AdInputType> inData)
    {
        foreach (var rule in _rules)
        {
           var chekedItems= inData.Datas.Where(data => rule.CheckItem(data)).ToList(); 
           if (chekedItems.Count == 0) continue;

           _currentRule = rule;
           foreach (var butch in chekedItems.Batch(rule.BatchSize))
           {             
               _stringRequest= _currentRule.CreateStringRequest(butch);
               RaiseSendDataRx.OnNext(this);                                 //Подготовиили данные и запустили RX событие, НУЖНО ДОЖИДАТЬЯ ОКОНЧАНИЯ ОБРАБОТКИ СОБЫТИЯ.
           }
        }

        //Конвеер обработки входных данных завершен  
        await Task.CompletedTask; 
    }
```

Думал вставит Delay с токеном отмены, но токен нужно постоянно переписывать в Обработчике события и это не будет работать.

```
 RaiseSendDataRx.OnNext(this); 
 await Task.Delay(-1, cts.Token);
```

Подскажите как лучше сделать?

Comment: Я понимаю что подписчик не должен влиять на издателя, т.е. если 10 подписчиков, то что делать издателю, ждать их всех? но у меня 1  подписчик на 1 процедуру обмена

Comment: Убрать await и будет ждать, ещё лучше использовать Task.ContinueWith и в него помещать остальную логику которая должна дождаться завершения.

Comment: Не понял. наппишите пожалуйста код в ответе

Comment: Примерно [так](https://github.com/ClnViewer/SpchListBuilder/blob/1c79d64a01a71388417a9d076eb2cb7ba87130d6/Metro/Pages/PageMain.xaml.cs#L118), наиболее простой и проверенный вариант. Только внутри выхлоп таска проверяйте, на canceled,fault и результат. Там в примере это тоже есть, в виде отдельной функции.

Comment: Кстати, await примерно так и организован судя по MS BCL.

Comment: Понял, вы говорите про синхронный вызов          status =  _transport.DataExchangeAsync(3000, provider, ct).GetAwaiter().GetResult();    Только с подпиской на события. спасибо!!!

Comment: RX — асинхронная штука по сути, она не управляется читателем, а наоборот управляет им. Если вам нужно, чтобы читатель «вытягивал» события, когда сможет, возможно, вам нужно просто `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Тогда как лучше сделать в моем случае?

Comment: Тут все таки издатель пихает события в цикле. Преобразование Observable к IEnumerable думаю не получится